# Math document containing some Sage calculations

Tags: math, word-processor

I need to write a short math text draft containing some Sage calculations. (I am a Sage novice.)

What software (or software combinations) you may suggest to do this?

Is it possible to do with TeXmacs? If yes, does it require to install any TeXmacs addons?

I prefer interactive software rather than LaTeX for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SageMath provides a [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) Kernel which allows you to create notebooks that mix text, (in markdown), and actual sage code, (including the results of running the code & rendering the markdown). See [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SageMath) or [here](http://davidlowryduda.com/a-jupyter-notebook-from-a-sagemath-tutorial/) for more.

While the display of latex or MathJax is still using the same syntax you can see the results immediately, *just press ctrl-enter to render the cell*.

The resulting page can be "downloaded" as html or pdf format.